# NLog - filters working with final/blackhole

Tags: nlog

I'd like to setup a way to easily include/exclude certain log messages from an all encompassing log file. Throughout my code I've logged messages based on a "Context" property, which I was then going to use in when conditions to include/exclude the message.

Here is my setup:

```
<logger writeTo=""
        final="true">
  <filters>        
  <when condition="equals('${event-properties:item=Context}', 'Database')"
        action="Log"/>
  </filters>
</logger>

<logger name="*"
        minlevel="Trace"
        writeTo="default"/>
```

My hope was that I could include/exclude any messages with Context='Database' in the first logger and then change the writeTo attribute to either include the message (i.e. writeTo="default") or exclude (i.e. writeTo="").

The issue seems to be that the first logger is including ALL messages and since final is set to true, no messages are allowed to follow through to the catch all logger? Only logs matching the condition in the logger one are written as expected, however ALL logs are being "finalized" by it.

Any ideas a to what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this instead (Remove `final="true"` and instead use `action="LogFinal"`)

```xml
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="Null" name="BlackHole" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger writeTo="BlackHole">
    <filters>        
       <when condition="equals('${event-properties:item=Context}', 'Database')"
         action="LogFinal"/>
    </filters>
  </logger>
</rules>
```

Looks like you have to specify an actual target to make the custom logger-filters work (Not dependent on LogLevel).

Comment: I was experimenting with that as well, but it doesn't work as I/you expected. In this case, the message is not caught by the "blackhole logger", and is picked up by the subsequent catch all. I *think* the 'action' attribute on the 'when' element is only relevant to other filters on that logger, i.e. "LogFinal" instructs the processing to not look at any subsequent 'when' elements?

Comment: There is a unit-test: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/19de4feb0a6f1292e9d0c69da5c75b73efda3ea1/tests/NLog.UnitTests/Config/RuleConfigurationTests.cs#L348

Comment: Looks like custom filters (not dependent on loglevel) doesn't work with empty `writeTo=""`. You have to use the old style with a Null-Target. Have updated the answer. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Null-target